# Nodejs / Javascript on input CTRL+C console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, cheerio

I currently use this script to restart my script.

```
catch(err){
    console.log(err)
    webhook.send(`Error monitoring **www.-.com**, restarting monitor.`)
    await browser.close()
    await sleep(monitorDelay)
    return checkStock(page, monitorURL, browser, instock)
  }
```

However, if I restart my script manually with CTRL+C, I want a seperate webhook.send which says "Monitoring stopped" instead. Does anyone know how you can detect my input "CTRL+C", then => ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think Ctrl+C is an input, or at least the program is not listening for inputs at that point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node you can catch a CTRL + C event by listening for the `EVENT SIGINT`

Sample script

```
console.log("In an infinite loop, CTRL + C to quit.")

// Start reading from stdin so we don't exit.
process.stdin.resume();


// catch ctrl+c event and exit normally
process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    console.log('Ctrl+C was keyed in, make you webhook call here');
    process.exit(0);
});
```

However as pointed out this is dependant on you running a node script file from the command prompt.

Comment: Worked to a certain extent. Console.log worked good but discord webhook gets overread or something. Probably something on my end, appreciate the help! :)